# Fabric: do everything as a particular user

Tags: python, deployment, build, fabric

My build and production deployment is connected using a keys by one user particular user that is shared across deployment and keys copied over during the machine spin up.

This user **deploy**, has ssh keys shared allowing ssh to any prod machine and between them.

Now my fabric build runs as user **Jenkins**.

How do I instruct fabric to execute everything as a particular user(**deploy** in this case)?The equivalent of `sudo su deploy`

I don’t want to do a `prefix` or `with` in every task. Rather set a global variable.

Jenkins is in the wheel group and has sudo perms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to execute commands as another user without using prefix or with.

The sudo function accepts a user which can be a global variable, if you like.

From the docs:

```
fabric.operations.sudo(command, shell=True, pty=True, 
                       combine_stderr=True, user=None, 
                       quiet=False, stdout=None, stderr=None)
```

You can simply call your tasks with

```
sudo(command, user=sudouser)
```

and set the sudouser to 'deploy' elsewhere.

In fact, this is no different from using the context:

```
with settings(sudo_user=sudouser):
      sudo(command)
```

In both cases, you should be able to change this sudo_user globally.